# How can I calculate the number of all rows when there are both LIMIT and JOIN clauses?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
select u.id, u.name,
       (select count(*) from users where name = u.name) as total
from users u
where u.name = 'anything'
order by id
limit 1
```

As you know, my query returns 1 user which has `anything` name. And `total` contains the number of all users which have `anything` name. Ok all fine.

---

Now I want to do the same thing when there are three `JOIN`s in the query. Please assume this:

```
select u.id, u.name, sum(r.reputation) rep
from users u
join reputation r on u.id = r.user_id
join posts_tags pt on r.post_id = pt.post_id
join tags t on pt.tag_id = t.id 
where u.name = 'anything' and t.name = 'mytag'
group by u.id, u.name
order by rep desc, u.id
limit 1
```

Now I want to know, how can I implement `total` part in this ^ query?

Comment: what is the result of `first` and `second` query?

Comment: @chiragsatapara Both return one row *(a user who has `anything` name)*, but the second one return the user who has more reputations in a specific tag and his name is `anything`.

Comment: this answer is helpful to you?

Comment: @chiragsatapara Nope .. The number of  `total` will be wrong in your query. Since those `join`s will reduce the matched rows but the subquery won't see it.

Comment: try this new query

Answer (score 0):

Try this query ,hope this give you the right result.

```
 select * , count(id) as total from  (select u.id, u.name, sum(r.reputation) rep 
        from users u
        join reputation r on u.id = r.user_id
        join posts_tags pt on r.post_id = pt.post_id
        join tags t on pt.tag_id = t.id 
        where u.name = 'anything' and t.name = 'mytag'
        group by u.id, u.name
        order by rep desc, u.id
        limit 1 ) as result
```